# What's the size of char string array element?

Tags: c, sizeof

I am learning c at the moment and I am slightly confused about the size element for a char string array element.

Take this example:

```
char *states[] = {
    "California", "Oregon",
    NULL, "Texas"
};
```

I wanted to see how I could get the size of the array, so I could count through it in a for loop. I found this calculation from some site to get the size of the array:

```
int size = sizeof(states) / sizeof(states[0]);
```

I'm a little confused, why is `sizeof(states[0])` 8 bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of pointers to characters. The total size of the array is

```
<number of elements> * <number of bytes for a char pointer>
```

The size of one of the members is the size of a char pointer (8 bytes on your system). So that gives you: `4*sizeof(char *)/sizeof(char *)` Thus the number of elements in the array.

To see the *length* of the string at position 0 you need:

```
strlen(states[0]);
```

Which will give you the 10 you're expecting.

Comment: Oh right, I see now. Thanks very much for the explanation, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`char *states[]` is an array of character pointers. So sizeof any element of the array will give the size of a pointer which in your case happens to be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

This is architecture dependent behavior.`sizeof(states[0])` is size of a character pointer as `states[0]` is a character pointer. In your machine size of `char` pointer happens to be `8`. Hence the output.

If you really want the size of the string, then better use something like `strnlen()` on `states[0]`.

Comment: Also notice that I have suggested `strnlen()` instead of `strlen()` because strnlen() provides more secure solution.

Comment: How is strnlen more secure? strlen will either crash safely if the string is malformed or the pointer is bad or give you a correct result. strnlen will either crash if the string is malformed or the pointer is bad, give you a correct result or give you a truncated result. How would adding a potentially truncated, incorrect result make anything more secure?

Comment: @Art My point was, you don't end up in an infinite loop if you don't get a NULL terminated string. It is easily possible to pass a string without proper NULL termination. Example in scanf you may end up reading a string without NULL termination. Instead of crashing having a truncated string is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
I'm a little confused, why is sizeof(states[0]) 8 bytes?
```

Because states is an array of char pointers .

So, `states[0]` is the first element of array and on your machine I think address is of 8 bytes.

That's why you are getting `8`